# unable to write the logs to log file using log4j through Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

I am working on Cucumber TestNg Gradle automation project. As I am new to Gradle and not able to figure the issue though I have put in appropriate log4j dependencies in build.gradle file. Can somebody look into this issue and provide the solutions or advise me on what went wrong due to which logs are not written to log file called "ApplicationLogs.log"

**Below is my project structure**

[image]

**Below is my Log4j.properties file contents**

## Root logger option

```
    log4j.rootLogger=INFO, RFILE,STDOUT
    
    # Console Appender
    log4j.appender.name=STDOUT
    log4j.appender.STDOUT=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
    log4j.appender.STDOUT.Target=System.out
    log4j.appender.STDOUT.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout 
    log4j.appender.STDOUT.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%-5p] [%c{1}] - [%M] %m%n
    
    
    # Rolling File Appender
    log4j.appender.name=RFILE
    log4j.appender.RFILE=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
    log4j.appender.RFILE.File=./Automation_Report/logs/ApplicationLogs.log
    log4j.appender.RFILE.threshold=INFO
    log4j.appender.RFILE.maxFileSize=25MB
    log4j.appender.RFILE.maxBackupIndex=100
    log4j.appender.RFILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.RFILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%-5p] [%c{1}] - [%M] %m%n
```

**Below is my build.gradle File Contents**

```
plugins {
        id 'java'
        id 'maven-publish'
        id 'java-library'
        id 'java-gradle-plugin'
        id 'application'
    }
            
    apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
       
        mavenCentral()
            jcenter()
    }
    
    task deleteGraphicsAssets(type: Delete) {
        delete "build"
    }

 version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
    sourceCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
        // This dependency is exported to consumers, that is to say found on their compile classpath.
        api 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1'
    
        // This dependency is used internally, and not exposed to consumers on their own compile classpath.
        implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:28.2-jre'
    
      
        implementation gradleApi()
        
        //Cucumber
        testImplementation  'io.cucumber:cucumber-java:4.8.0'
        
        //compile group: 'io.cucumber', name: 'cucumber-jvm', version: '4.8.0', ext: 'pom'
         testImplementation  'io.cucumber:cucumber-jvm:4.8.0'
        
        compile group: 'io.cucumber', name: 'cucumber-core', version: '4.8.0'
       // testImplementation  'io.cucumber:cucumber-core:4.8.0'
       
       compile group: 'io.cucumber', name: 'cucumber-testng', version: '4.8.0'
       //testImplementation  'io.cucumber:cucumber-testng:4.8.0'
        
       implementation  'io.cucumber:cucumber-picocontainer:4.7.4'
        testImplementation  'io.cucumber:cucumber-gherkin:5.1.0'
       
        
       //TestNg
       // testImplementation 'org.testng:testng:6.14.3'
        testCompile group: 'org.testng', name: 'testng', version: '6.14.3'
        
       //Reports
       testImplementation  'com.aventstack:extentreports:4.1.7'
       testImplementation  'com.aventstack:extentreports-cucumber4-adapter:1.0.12'
       
       //Maven Compiler , Surefire Plugin ,Poi
       testImplementation  'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2'
       testImplementation  'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1' 
       testImplementation 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:4.1.2'
        
        //Log4j & SLF4J
          compile group: 'log4j', name: 'log4j', version: '1.2.17'
       
        // #Rest Assured Apis
         testImplementation 'io.rest-assured:rest-assured:3.3.0'
         testImplementation 'org.json:json:20180813'
         testImplementation 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1'
         
         
         
         //#Selenium Apis
         compile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-server', version: '3.141.59'
         implementation 'com.paulhammant:ngwebdriver:1.1.4'
         
         compile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-htmlunit-driver', version: '2.52.0'
         implementation 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:4.0.0-alpha-4'
         
          //testImplementation 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:2.2'
      
        }

test {
        testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
        systemProperties System.getProperties()
    }

configurations {
        cucumberRuntime.extendsFrom testImplementation
    }
    
    
      task cucumber() {
        dependsOn assemble,testClasses
        doLast {
            javaexec {
                main = "io.cucumber.core.cli.Main"
                classpath = configurations.cucumberRuntime + sourceSets.main.output + sourceSets.test.output
                
                
                args = ['--plugin', 'pretty', 
                
                        '--plugin', 'json:target/AppleBrands.json', 
                        
                        '--plugin',  'com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter:Report',
                        
                     
                          '--glue','com.apple.brands.test.stepdefinition',
                        
                          'src/test/resources','src/main/java',
    
                        '--tags', '@Api'         
                    ]
                      
            }
           
        }
      }
      
     
       
       tasks.test {
        finalizedBy cucumber
    }
```

Comment: Please provide the github code base to solve the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue.

The problem was that you didn't use the LoggerHelper.

This is my project structure :

[image]

Updated LoggerHelper class :

[image]

To test whether LoggerHelper is working or not. I added one Test class with main method :

[image]

Console :

[image]

The log generated file.

[image]

Comment: For me its not still working. Not sure what is the issue. Need to check other alternative as  freshly create project from scratch and see.

Comment: I think i have used this code before good that their is no errors but the logs are not written to file.

Comment: @BalajiSingh.Y I saw the code. The project is not a gradle project. This is creating an issue. Please create a project from scratch. Can please accept this answer if it is helpful ?

Comment: B : This is a gradle project hence forth we see an .gradle and build.gradle files present and more over every time i build my project it creates an build folder.

Comment: @BalajiSingh.Y There is pom.xml as well

Comment: B : Anyways thanks for your Help. I have resolved the issue now everything is working as expected and even the logs are getting generated.

Comment: @BalajiSingh.Y Can you accept this answer and upvote as well.

Answer (score 0):

After doing lot of analysis and comparing i found the solution to my question. The solution is very simple only mistake that i need to remove the unwanted plugins used due to which it created all of issues.

When I removed the application plugin as shown below in plugin section it started working properly and even logs started working.

```
plugins {
        id 'java'
        id 'maven-publish'
        id 'java-library'
        id 'java-gradle-plugin'
        
    }
```