# log4j.PropertyConfigurator error during runtime Says no suitable method found for configure(FileInputStream)

Tags: java, gradle, log4j, build.gradle

I am getting the below error during build phase for Log4j. It say no such method found for configure(FileInputSteam).

Below is full contex of error.

Task :compileJava FAILED

```
E:\GadleDemoProj\src\main\java\com\hal\brands\helper\Logger\LoggerHelper.java:28: error: no suitable method found for configure(FileInputStream)
                        PropertyConfigurator.configure(inputStream);
                                            ^
    method PropertyConfigurator.configure(Properties) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; FileInputStream cannot be converted to Properties)
    method PropertyConfigurator.configure(String) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; FileInputStream cannot be converted to String)
    method PropertyConfigurator.configure(URL) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; FileInputStream cannot be converted to URL)
```

**My Logger class is as below :**

```
 public class LoggerHelper {
    
    private static boolean root = false;
    
    public static Logger getLogger(Class clas) {
        if(root)
            return Logger.getLogger(clas);
        
        /*PropertyConfigurator.configure(ResourceHelper
                .getResourcePath("configfile/log4j.properties"));*/
        FileInputStream inputStream = null;
        try {
            inputStream = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\main\\resources\\configFile\\log4j.properties");
            
            PropertyConfigurator.configure(inputStream);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        root = true;
        return Logger.getLogger(clas);
    }

}
```

Comment: Which version of log4j are you using ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the code to this :

```
public class LoggerHelper {
    
    private static boolean root = false;
    
    public static Logger getLogger(Class clas) {
        if(root)
            return Logger.getLogger(clas);
        
        /*PropertyConfigurator.configure(ResourceHelper
                .getResourcePath("configfile/log4j.properties"));*/
        FileInputStream inputStream = null;
        try {
            inputStream = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\main\\resources\\configFile\\log4j.properties");
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.load(inputStream);
            
            PropertyConfigurator.configure(properties);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        root = true;
        return Logger.getLogger(clas);
    }

}
```

Comment: B  : Thanks a lot the above said error is gone but i see that its still not writing to log file under this path  "./Automation_Report/logs/ApplicationLogs.log".

Comment: B - I have  added my log4j.properties  above. I am not sure why it is not writing logs to log file

Comment: @BalajiSingh.Y Ok wait looking into it.

Comment: @BalajiSingh.Y Can you raise a different question for this ? You can't ask multiple questions in single.

Comment: B:  Please i need this one. Tried with all possibilities but not sure what went wrong

Comment: @BalajiSingh.Y Ok !! which appender will append log in the file ?

Comment: Name of the appender is RFile 

and i am appening using the below statement

log4j.appender.RFILE.Append= true;

Comment: @BalajiSingh.Y See this example : https://howtodoinjava.com/log4j/how-to-configure-log4j-using-properties-file/

Comment: @BalajiSingh.Y May be this will help you.

Comment: As you asked on raising a different question , i hope i have already it on stack which might give you some more details  Ref : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63778957/unable-to-write-the-logs-to-log-file-using-log4j-through-gradle

Comment: @BalajiSingh.Y I found the solution adding it.

Comment: B : Thanks for your quick response and issue for the first query got solved hence marking the first issue to  closure.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221646/discussion-between-balaji-singh-y-and-anish-b).

Comment: B : Please find the GitHub link : https://github.com/BalajiSingh/GradleProj.git

Comment: In Command Prompt please be navigate to Project Directory and then give following commands  one by one  :  1) gradle clean  2) gradle build   3) gradle cucumber ( this command will execute the tests )